# EditText box focus

Tags: android, textbox

In my application i have 3 edit text boxes ,in that in first two edit boxes user will enter the input.
In the third edit text box i have to multiply these two values  and i have to display  when the user touch the third edit text box.

Please anybody help me.

I tried for this:

```
total.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("insidefocus");
                    String tot=String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(price.getText().toString()))*(Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString())));
                    System.out.println("tot="+tot);
                    total.setText(tot);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? Text not showing?

Comment: Ya text is not showing..only the keyboard is showing..

Comment: I solved my problem.Mistake is my side.I did some chilly mistake.I misplaced the code.Actually this code should be done before button pressed.i placed that code inside button click.Thanks to all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use can use **onClickListener** instead of **onKeyListener** and do ur functionlity like adding two textbox values and set the result in third textbox.

```
total.setonClickListener (new View.onClickListener () {

            @Override
            public boolean onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tot=txt1.getText.toSting()+txt2.getText.toString();
                total.setText(tot);

            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried for that also its not working..Its not coming into the onclick method itself.

Comment: I solved my problem.Mistake is my side.I did some chilly mistake.I misplaced the code.Actually this code should be done before button pressed.i placed that code inside button click.Thanks to all..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of onclick and onfocus gain listener:

```
total.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {               
public void onClick(View arg0) {                            
    Calculate();                    
}
});

total.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
if(hasFocus==true)
{
    Calculate();
}
}
});

Calculate(){
    String tot=String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(price.getText().toString()))*(Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString())));
    total.setText(tot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText mEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText mEditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            final Button result=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        result.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String a, b;
                Integer vis;
                a = mEditText.getText().toString();
                b = mEditText1.getText().toString();
                vis = Integer.parseInt(a) + Integer.parseInt(b);
                mEditText2.setText(vis.toString());
                mEditText2.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Third is your third editbiox

```
       third.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int one = Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText().toString());
            int two = Integer.parseInt(txt2.getText().toString());
            int result = one+two ;
            third.setText(String.valueOf(result));

        }
    });
```